# LaTeX indent for \iff error in vim

Tags: vimrc, indentation, filetype-tex, plugin-vimtex

With the minimal vimrc (with vimtex plugin):

```
set nocp
filetype plugin indent on
syntax on
set st=2
set acd
set wildmenu
set wildmode=longest,list,full
let $USRPLUGD=$HOME.'\vimfiles\myvim\plugged'
let $USRTEMPD=$HOME.'\vimfiles\myvim\vimtemp'
call plug#begin( $USRPLUGD )
" for latex
Plug 'lervag/vimtex'
call plug#end()

let g:tex_flavor = "latex"
let g:vimtex_quickfix_open_on_warning = 0
let g:vimtex_quickfix_mode = 2
let g:vimtex_view_general_viewer='sumatrapdf'


let g:vimtex_compiler_latexmk = {
            \ 'backend' : 'process',
            \ 'background' : 1,
            \ 'build_dir' : $USRTEMPD,
            \ 'callback' : 1,
            \ 'continuous' : 1,
            \ 'executable' : 'latexmk',
            \ 'options' : [
            \   '-verbose',
            \   '-file-line-error',
            \   '-synctex=1',
            \   '-interaction=nonstopmode',
            \ ],
            \}
```

I found that the indent of tex source file is not work properly for `\iff`. Suppose we have a `test.tex` then after `gg=G`,

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\begin{document}
\section{Test}
\[
    a>b
\]
\end{document}
```

However, this indent scheme seems not work properly for `\iff` command:

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\begin{document}
\section{Test}
\[
    a>b \Longleftrightarrow a-b>0.
\]
Not work for \verb|\iff|
    \[
        a>b \iff a-b>0.
        \]
        \end{document}
```

As I have observed, we can replace `\iff` by `\Longleftrightarrow`. Is there any other solution such that the indention works for `\iff`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem you are describing seems to be clearly concerning the [vimtex plugin](https://github.com/lervag/vimtex). The proper solution is therefore to raise this issue where it should be raised, i.e. at [vimtex's issue tracker](https://github.com/lervag/vimtex/issues).

However, no need, I just fixed the issue, so if you update your plugins, then this indentation issue should be resolved. Please open an issue at the issue tracker if the problem should persist, or if you have other issures relating to vimtex.